# Can I perform a MAX over a pair of columns?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I would like to execute the following:

```
SELECT person, MAX( (date, priority) ) FROM table GROUP BY person;
```

It would return a `person`, `date` and `priority` row for each distinct value in the `person` column.  The `date` and `priority` are chosen such that the `date` value is maximised, and the maximum `priority` that occurs *on that date* is chosen.

As an example, running the query on this table

```
person |     date     | priority
---------------------------------
   1   | '2014-01-01' |    10
   1   | '2014-01-02' |     2
   1   | '2014-01-02' |     3
```

should result in

```
person |     date     | priority
---------------------------------
   1   | '2014-01-02' |     3
```

Postgres complains about this particular attempt:

```
ERROR:  function max(record) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types.
You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Is there a way that I can achieve this?  Anything that works with Postgres will be acceptable but if a solution is more standard then so much the better.

Comment: Does it mean that you always want the date for the biggest priority per person?

Comment: No, I want the biggest date, and the biggest priority on that date.  I will improve my example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does this fits your needs?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (person)
       person, date, priority
  FROM table
 ORDER BY person, date DESC, priority DESC;
```

Comment: I think this is the neatest solution.

Answer (score 7):

Use a windowing function.

```
select * from (
select person, date, priority, row_number() over(partition by person order by date desc,priority desc) as p
from table
) as foo
where p=1;
```

[SQL Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/66ba9) for you to play with.

Answer (score 0):

You are interested in the latest date. This is what you need to concentrate to in the first place:

```
SELECT person, MAX(date) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY person;
```

Now, to get the biggest priority for the person/date combination use a sub-query:

```
SELECT t.person, tm.max_date, MAX(t.priority) 
FROM
(SELECT person, MAX(date) max_date
 FROM table1 
 GROUP BY person) tm 
INNER JOIN table1 t ON t.person = tm.person and t.date = tm.max_date
GROUP BY t.person, tm.max_date
```

This is as generic solution as you can think. However, if you have one of the latest version of postgresql you can make it better with window functions